# How to enable/disable a line of code without the usage of if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say that you have 2 print statements:

```
print ("Hi")
print ("Hello")
```

And you comment out the second line resulting in:

```
print ("Hi")
#print ("Hello")
```

This would only execute the first line on runtime, ignoring the second. My question is, is there a way to enable the second line during runtime without having to manually go to the script and remove it?

I'd like to do through **user input**, but also **without the usage of if statements** because my code is getting over saturated with "ifs" and wish to do something different.

Comment: I read this question as "how can I conditionally execute code without using conditionals". What...?

Comment: but whats wrong with if conditions, and does the saturation mean a overcrowded?

Comment: There is no one obvious answer for this.
If you concerned with making your code messy and saturated you can try to follow functional or OO paradigm. Just saying.

Comment: You could write a disgusting method that reads your current script, finds every line starting with `#` then evaluates `thatLine[1:]`...

Comment: Its pretty hard to divine what you need. Try putting all the options in a dictionary using acceptable user responses as the keys.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your conditionally *overcrowded* code.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing wrong with "over Saturating of if conditions" but however if you want to still find a way here is a one, but it may not guarantee finest result depending upon what you want. and it only works if you already know the output.

taking and trivial example suppose you want to print "hello" if user inputs `1` and "hi" when user inputs `0`.

```
dec = {0: "hello", 1: "hi"}

try:
    print(dec[0])

except KeyError:

    print("wrong entry!")
```

i hope it helps!

Comment: Well, this is more or less what I wanted I assume. Thanks